# node heroku error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: heroku, mongoose

I have this CRUD app on heroku connected to Mlab. I have 2 different routes (that submits from a form) data to MLab and an image to an S3 bucket. One route works completely fine. The other route, which is very similar to the first, minus some text inputs, throws an error on Heroku whenever you submit. It actually works fine locally though. If I remove all of the logic associated with the image upload it works too. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. I can't figure out why it would work on one almost identical route, but not the other.

This is my app.js code that connects mongoose and router

```
var router = express.Router();
var eventRoutes = require('./routes/event');
var adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin');
var venueRoutes = require('./routes/venue');

app.use('/', router);
app.use(eventRoutes);
app.use(adminRoutes);
app.use(venueRoutes);

mongoose.connect(process.env.HOTNIGHTDATABASEURL);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
  var date = new Date()
  console.log('Server Spinning Up at ' + date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', 
  {hour12: true,}));
});
```

This is the config for S3 and the post route for the route that works.

```
//Multers3 and AWS s3 setup
var s3 = new aws.S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.HOTNIGHTEVENTSBUCKETID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.HOTNIGHTEVENTSBUCKETSECRET,
  region: 'us-east-2'
});

var upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({   
    s3: s3,
    acl: 'public-read',
    bucket: 'hot-night-events',
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now().toString())
    }
  })
});

router.post('/events', upload.single('image'), function(req, res){
var event = new Event({
... for brevity left out data collected from form
});
    event.save(function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    });
});
```

This is the other route (in a different file) that doesn't work:

```
//Multers3 and AWS s3 setup
    var s3 = new aws.S3({
      accessKeyId: process.env.HOTNIGHTEVENTSBUCKETID,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.HOTNIGHTEVENTSBUCKETSECRET,
      region: 'us-east-2'
    });

    var upload = multer({
      storage: multerS3({   
        s3: s3,
        acl: 'public-read',
        bucket: 'hot-night-events',
        metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
        },
        key: function (req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, Date.now().toString())
        }
      })
    });

    router.post('/venues', upload.single('venueImage'), function(req, res){
    var venue = new Venue({
    ... for brevity left out data collected from form
    });
        venue.save(function(err, data){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.redirect('/');
            }
        });
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the error that you encounter?

Comment: @SatnamSandhu .The error is -- Error: ECONNREFUSED 169.254.169.254:80
at Object._errnoException (util.js.992:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js.1014:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as complete] (net.js.1186:14)
I'm pretty sure the IP address in the error is for the S3 bucket.

Comment: Was this resolved @JordanT